# Azure AD B2C password expiration notification

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have numerous Azure B2C tenants - around 30. We have noticed - and customers are now making complaints - that the passwords 'seem' to be expiring. However, there is no password expiry notification being sent. (This in addition to the B2C error message for expired passwords of "Invalid username or password." not being very informative).

These are local accounts and use the email address for signon. Are there any clues about why no notification (emails) are sent prior to password expiry?

Note also that apparently there is no password expiry policy for B2C:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861060-aadb2c-password-expiration

This is the data coming back from the B2CGraphClient:

```
{
  "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
  "objectType": "User",
  "objectId": "<redacted objectid>",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "ageGroup": null,
  "assignedLicenses": [],
  "assignedPlans": [],
  "city": null,
  "companyName": null,
  "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
  "country": null,
  "createdDateTime": "2018-03-08T00:46:29Z",
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "department": null,
  "dirSyncEnabled": null,
  "displayName": "Super Admin",
  "employeeId": null,
  "facsimileTelephoneNumber": null,
  "givenName": null,
  "immutableId": null,
  "isCompromised": null,
  "jobTitle": null,
  "lastDirSyncTime": null,
  "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mailNickname": "<redacted other id>",
  "mobile": null,
  "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
  "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
  "otherMails": [],
  "passwordPolicies": null,
  "passwordProfile": null,
  "physicalDeliveryOfficeName": null,
  "postalCode": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "provisionedPlans": [],
  "provisioningErrors": [],
  "proxyAddresses": [],
  "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2018-06-11T16:53:48Z",
  "showInAddressList": null,
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "<redacted email address>"
    }
  ],
  "sipProxyAddress": null,
  "state": null,
  "streetAddress": null,
  "surname": null,
  "telephoneNumber": null,
  "thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaEditLink": "directoryObjects/<redacted objectid>/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/thumbnailPhoto",
  "usageLocation": null,
  "userIdentities": [],
  "userPrincipalName": "<redacted other id>@<redacted tenant>.onmicrosoft.com",
  "userState": null,
  "userStateChangedOn": null,
  "userType": "Guest"
}
```

Here is the data coming back from `Get-MSOLUser`:

```
ExtensionData                          : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AlternateEmailAddresses                : {}
AlternateMobilePhones                  : {}
AlternativeSecurityIds                 : {}
BlockCredential                        : False
City                                   :
CloudExchangeRecipientDisplayType      :
Country                                :
Department                             :
DirSyncProvisioningErrors              : {}
DisplayName                            : Super Admin
Errors                                 :
Fax                                    :
FirstName                              :
ImmutableId                            :
IndirectLicenseErrors                  : {}
IsBlackberryUser                       : False
IsLicensed                             : False
LastDirSyncTime                        :
LastName                               :
LastPasswordChangeTimestamp            : 6/11/2018 4:53:48 PM
LicenseReconciliationNeeded            : False
Licenses                               : {}
LiveId                                 : <redacted id>
MSExchRecipientTypeDetails             :
MobilePhone                            :
ObjectId                               : <redacted objectid>
Office                                 :
OverallProvisioningStatus              : None
PasswordNeverExpires                   :
PasswordResetNotRequiredDuringActivate :
PhoneNumber                            :
PortalSettings                         :
PostalCode                             :
PreferredDataLocation                  :
PreferredLanguage                      :
ProxyAddresses                         : {}
ReleaseTrack                           :
ServiceInformation                     : {}
SignInName                             : <redacted other id>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com
SoftDeletionTimestamp                  :
State                                  :
StreetAddress                          :
StrongAuthenticationMethods            : {}
StrongAuthenticationPhoneAppDetails    : {}
StrongAuthenticationProofupTime        :
StrongAuthenticationRequirements       : {}
StrongAuthenticationUserDetails        : Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails
StrongPasswordRequired                 :
StsRefreshTokensValidFrom              : 6/11/2018 4:53:48 PM
Title                                  :
UsageLocation                          :
UserLandingPageIdentifierForO365Shell  :
UserPrincipalName                      : <redacted other id>@<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com
UserThemeIdentifierForO365Shell        :
UserType                               : Guest
ValidationStatus                       : Healthy
WhenCreated                            : 3/8/2018 12:46:29 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe passwords are expiring because the local accounts have been created *without* the **passwordPolicies** property being set to `DisablePasswordExpiration`.

Therefore, passwords are expiring after 90 days and unfortunately, the affected end-users aren't notified of this.

If a local account is created using a built-in policy, then this policy sets this property to `DisablePasswordExpiration`.

If a local account is created using either a custom policy or Azure AD Graph API, then you must set the property to `DisablePasswordExpiration`.

For Azure AD Graph API, see [the **Create consumer user accounts** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#create-consumer-user-accounts) of [the **Azure AD B2C: Use the Azure AD Graph API** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet), for examples of this.

To fix this up, you might have to:

1. PATCH all of the local accounts in order to set the **passwordPolicies** property to `DisablePasswordExpiration`.
2. Tell the affected end-users that they must reset passwords.

Comment: Thanks Chris yes we use the Graph API ATM so although it  would be a pain to switch off we could do so.

The upshot seems to be either no password expiration or password expiration that has no notification (or hint in the login screen when using the old password). Has there been any rumor to add the notification capability?

Comment: Hi @GMac. You can switch to the sign-up-only policy that supports changing an expired password. You can also vote for the expiration feature on [the feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861060-aadb2c-password-expiration).

Comment: Thanks @Chris Padgett. Unfortunately we can only use the signup/signin policy since we need UI customization and in fact we suppress the signup aspect as we are invite only. Yes I have voted for that feature - 30 votes and counting!